# Suddenly server cannot connect due to SocketException

Tags: c#, client-server

I am using this server example from MSND: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

and from some reason my server refuse to connect at this function at `_listener.Bind(localEndPoint);` with error `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`

Until a few minutes ago I had no problems Sarver connect without problems and suddenly it happens

```
public static void StartListening(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
{
    _isServerRunning = true;
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
    // The DNS name of the computer
    // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
    //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    //IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.100"); //ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    _listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        _listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        _listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            _listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                _listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    //Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}
```

What does this error means ?

Comment: Not the point of the questions but using async IO and waiting for its completion does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely means that the local port is still reserved.  This can be idther because another process is still runnoing and holding the sockewt open, or because the timeout period defined by th dSO_LINGER socket option is not timed out.  I'm not familiar with c# but there should be a way to set th elinger timeout.

You can tell the current status of the socket by using the netstat command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find some solutions here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/470766.aspx